# Using SUMIFS to pull YTD sales data in excel

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

I am looking for a way to pull out YTD data for a spreadsheet that has the following in the A,B,C Columns.

I want it to be able to pull the current month of the year and compare YTD sales in the C column from that.

I have used =SUM(IF(YEAR(A:A)=2016,C:C,0)) to get the entire year data but want just jan - current month for each year listed.

`YTD Sales Through May
2008

2009

2010

2011

2012

2013

2014

2015

2016`

```
Jan-03  17  $86,625
Feb-03  17  $107,900
Mar-03  21  $103,400
Apr-03  17  $112,050
May-03  20  $75,145
Jun-03  26  $198,800
Jul-03  14  $80,695
Aug-03  19  $50,940
Sep-03  26  $152,380
Oct-03  23  $109,380
Nov-03  19  $113,875
Dec-03  21  $149,275
Jan-04  30  $113,110
Feb-04  17  $109,493
Mar-04  15  $69,690
Apr-04  25  $123,145
May-04  24  $136,685
Jun-04  30  $148,495
Jul-04  21  $138,990
Aug-04  29  $131,005
Sep-04  38  $165,790
Oct-04  43  $173,190
Nov-04  41  $253,915
Dec-04  39  $217,650
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use this formula and change the Year to what you want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$24)<=MONTH(TODAY()))*(YEAR($A$1:$A$24)=2016)*$C$1:$C$24)
```

If you want all the years YTD in one formula you can:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$24)<=MONTH(TODAY()))*(YEAR($A$1:$A$24)={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016})*$C$1:$C$24)
```

To make the formula more dynamic, so it grows and contracts with the size of the data use this;

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))<=MONTH(TODAY()))*(YEAR($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))={2004,2005})*$C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))
```

Make sure that the references `$A$2` and `$C$2` refer to the first cell of data and not the title row.

With Array formula's calculations being exponential we need to limit the reference to only the dataset size.  All the `INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))` accomplish this.  It will automatically set the last row with a number in column A as the last row of the dataset.

So as the dataset grows or shrinks we will not be doing any unneeded iterations.

Change `{2004,2005}` to any number of years desired.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am getting #VALUE! as the response though and is there a way to do it so it pulls from A:A as i will be adding more to it.

Comment: Both your formula and this are Array formulas, full column references should be avoided as the calculations are exponential.  I will edit my formula to be dynamic.  But you need to ensure that the dates are true dates, as in numbers that look like dates and not text in the form of dates.  Also that your data has no text or errors in it, it is one of those two that is the cause of your error.

Comment: This works great. Is it possible to change it so that it ends at the month before the current one. Ie YTD through april?

Comment: Yes just change the `<=` to `<` @Mbrazitis